# jQuery change value with val() - element does not always show new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change value of an element with `$('#voucherID_id').val('LF3L3DAF6X');`. This works most of the time, however at certain cases (perhaps due to my way of using jQUery + Google Chrome) the element does not show the new value. However, if I click on the element then the value changes.

As an illustration. I have an input element with value `LF3L3DAF6X`, however it display entirely different value `QUXJOJJUDZ` on the browser. What might cause this ?

**Screenshot:**

[image: FTIR in Biometrics]

**HTML**

```
<div class="controls">
    <input id="voucherID_id" name="voucherID" type="text" value="LF3L3DAF6X">
    <span class="help-inline"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if (elem.is(":checkbox") && !nested){
    elem.prop('checked', aData[propertyName]);
}
else if ((elem.is(":text") || elem.is(":input[type='number']") || elem.is(":input[type='hidden']")) && !nested){
    elem.val(aData[propertyName]);
}
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried

Comment: Cant depict exact behaviour without seeing the code.

Comment: friend please add your code, instead of screenshot..

Comment: I provided the code to change the value using jQuery. What other code I should provide ?

Comment: Better as code is a working example with [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) :) .

Comment: Please provide the HTML code wrapping your `#voucherID_id`

Comment: Post your jQuery too..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

input type="text" placeholder="Voucher ID" id="Voucher"

JQuery

var VoucherID='WTWEYUYQWHB'

$('#Voucher').val(VoucherID);